# python-mysql in Cloud DataFlowRunner?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, mysql-python, apache-beam

I currently have some code that queries mysql. I'd like to run this code as part of a Apache Beam Pipeline in the DataFlowRunner. Each time I try to integrate MysqlDB the job hangs. It works fine with the DirectRunner and prior to me adding MySQLDB dependencies.

Here's my [setup.py](https://github.com/datadidit/sandbox/blob/master/python/apache_beam/wordcount/setup.py)

I've added comments to the lines that appear to cause the DataFlowRunner to hang.

I've tried running the example wordcount with just the `apt-get` and the `pypi` dependency.

Expected result is to be able to add MySQL deps and still be able to run the wordcount exampe.

Update: See [README](https://github.com/datadidit/sandbox/tree/master/python/apache_beam/wordcount) for what I ended up doing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work.  There are strong constraints on what your code can do within a Dataflow job.  Specifically, you should make zero assumptions about the environment.  You should assume no networking, no disk, no operating system.  All you should be doing is manipulating data,

Comment: @Kolban thanks for getting back to me. Yeah the more I bang my head against this the less likely I think it'll ever work. Apache Beams docs indicate that it supports [non python deps](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#nonpython) but it must not work in all runners.

Thinking I'll need to just use https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL . Hoping that can install in a pipeline.

Comment: For anyone else who goes down this rabbit hole just use `mysql+pymysql` as your URL if you're using SQLAlchemy. If you're not using ORM just use pymysql.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who goes down this rabbit hole just use mysql+pymysql as your URL if you're using SQLAlchemy. If you're not using ORM just use pymysql.